# c#/Mono solution not building on remote Dokku server

Tags: c#, .net, docker, mono, dokku

I am new to mono and to deploying c# apps on Dokku.

After pushing my app to the remote dokku server, the build start and I, miraculously, only get 3 build errors.

```
   IUserRepository.cs(7,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IRepositoryV2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
   IAuthenticationUnitOfWork.cs(6,69): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IUnitOfWork' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
   IAuthenticationUnitOfWork.cs(11,3): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `IRepositoryV2' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

These are all references from one solution in my project to another. The whole solution contains about 15 projects.

When further looking at the build output, I also see the some NuGet packages are not being found/getting resolved:

```
   /tmp/build/mono/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'FluentValidation' not resolved

   /tmp/build/Reflect.v2.sln (default targets) ->
   (Build target) ->
   /tmp/build/Reflect.Data.EF/Reflect.Data.EF.csproj (default targets) ->
   /tmp/build/mono/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets (ResolveAssemblyReferences target) ->

   /tmp/build/mono/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'EntityFramework' not resolved
   /tmp/build/mono/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Npgsql' not resolved
   /tmp/build/mono/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets:  warning : Reference 'Npgsql.EntityFramework' not resolved
```

I suspect that these warnings may be the indicators of the actual problem. However, I have double checked all my NuGet references in my projects, all all looks fine. The subsequent packages.config files also look good.

Also, everything builds fine on my local machine. And I am using this buildpack: https://github.com/adamburgess/heroku-buildpack-mono

What could be the culprit? Thanks!

This my full build output: https://gist.github.com/Corstiaan84/d4798dd1e84486dee2945845293de0f3

Comment: what version of mono is this?

Comment: Version 4.5.1.0. The buildpack automatically pulls down the latest release (don't know if this is good practice for production usage but let worry about that later). Any ideas? Im running 4.2.4 on my local machine.

Comment: Same issue when using 4.2.2.0...

Comment: 4.5.1.0 is not the mono version, but the .NET profile version FYI

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you. Any ideas on the problem? Need some more info perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up removing the projects in questions from the solution, creating a new project and re-adding the files from the removed project to the new project. Don't know what exactly fixed this but now it's working.